# Master Key vs Password Certificate Encryption in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, encryption

We can encrypt certificates in SQL both by the database master key, and the other option is by password. I want to know the advantages and disadvantages of DMK encryption. Does password usage make the certificate more secure?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We can encrypt certificates in SQL both by the database master key, and the other option is by password.

You can do both at the same time, which is preferable.

> I want to know the advantages and disadvantages of DMK encryption.

The big two are:

- If you forget the password or can't use the SMK (service master key), you can still open the Certificate (think AG, DBM, etc.)
- You can use Transparent Decryption which removes the need to specifically open by password

Comment: how to do it both at the same time? Does syntax allow us to do it? @SeanGallardy

Comment: @ElGrig When you create the certificate, a DMK must already exist and it is automatically encrypted using the MDK. If you choose to use the `PASSWORD` clause then it will be encrypted by both.